# How to log user details who restarted a service in linux

Tags: linux, debian

Is it possible to log the user name who restarted/stopped/started a service in linux ? so that i can know who restarted a particular service and at what time.

Comment: Typically the only user who can stop/start/restart a service is `root`. If it's done through something like `sudo service ...` or something, you'll need to make sure `sudo` is configured to log its actions (it usually is).

Comment: For Debian you can look at the /var/log/auth.log file to see everything done with `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

In case this is not actually a security issue but more of management, you could also write a wrapper script.

In case of Ubuntu-like Linux-es it would be replacing the original **service** command which logs the username somewhere and actually runs *sudo* to do service restart.

In case you don't use sudo and have specific privileges for every user, that script can just log the username and then do the service restart.